# How to gitignore a file on remote branch git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a branch where I have a file called keys.py.
The file contains some private keys I do not want to share with other on my repository, but I'd like to leave a file called keys.py inside the repo to be used like a template. I also need to avoid tracking other people's changes to key.py.

I tried to push the template file keys.py and then I created a .gitignore file to ignore keys.py but it seems like it has no effect...

I am missing something but i can not figure out how to solve my problem... any hint?

Comment: I guess you also have to commit the file removal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the common approach for this problem is to have a keys.py.example, and when someone clones the repo, copy it to keys.py and change the values as necessary (you can write it on the README). You can do it with this steps:

- Run  `git rm keys.py`, so the keys.py that you have on the repo gets removed
- Create or add  the line `keys.py` on your .gitignore file
- Create keys.py.example with the default values
- `git add .` to add all this changes on the commit
- `git commit` to commit the removal of the file from the repo, the example file and the gitignore changes

Usually this kind of values goes on a .env file instead of keys.py. I can see you are using python, so you will need to use [this package](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv).

Answer (score 2):

Yup, `.gitignore` has no effect on paths that already have been added to the repository.

For me, the best solution for your problem is to have the real `keys.py` outside of the repository, say in a file like `$HOME/.appname/keys.py`. The question then is how your application finds this file. A good possibility:

- Configure the file name in an environment variable.
- Have the application look into `$HOME/.appname/keys.py` as a default.

Comment: A comment on the last bullet point: Git tracks symlinks as symlinks (it does not follow them), so a change in the underlying file will not be reflected. Even so, symlinking in this way puts a constraint on where the project may be placed, which makes it fragile. Avoid.

Comment: True enough, @jsageryd. I've removed that, it just confuses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your replies!
I solved the problem in a tricky way:

1. Renamed key.py into key_template.py
2. Added key.py into .gitignore
3. Added to the readme the instruction to create key.py from key_template.py